# Propensity scores with past observations

Tags: propensity-scores, matching, intervention-analysis

Theoretical question here: is it possible (and justifiable) to do propensity score matching when all control units come from a different time period?

For example, imagine there is a programme for 18 year olds that is introduced at time period T. Some individuals are treated and some aren't. You could do PSM to match with untreated individuals in time period T, but could you also look at the previous period T-1 instead?

Logically, the previous period may give better controls because you can identify the individuals that would have been treated in period T-1 (but were not, because their cohort was a year too early). On the other hand, if outcomes vary over time, variation between the treated units at time T and the control units at time T-1 may be driven by time trends. And if all treated units are from time T and all control from T-1, a time dummy variable is not possible because it would be the same as the treatment variable!

Maybe there is a better method for analysing the causal effects of an intervention when the control units all come from past time periods?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you suggest, the question isn't "can I do propensity score matching" but rather "can I estimate a causal effect". You can do propensity score matching on whatever dataset you want; whether it produces a matched sample from which can estimate a causal effect is totally separate. The ability to estimate a causal effect using methods that rely on covariate adjustment (include matching) depends on the validity of the assumption of (mean) conditional exchangeability.

If there is a cohort effect (those in the prior time point are fundamentally different from those in a later cohort in a way relevant to the outcome), then allowing imbalance on cohort membership by matching with a previous cohort would allow confounding to remain. For example, if that cohort experienced a new technology or a new cultural mileu (e.g., because of the invention of AI or the occurrence of a global pandemic), you might expect individuals from those two cohorts to differ in findmanetal ways, and allowing imbalance on cohort would allow bias to remain in the effect estimate.

On the other hand, just as you described, if there isn't a cohort effect, the previous cohort may contain individuals that are very similar to the treated individuals but simply didn't receive treatment because it hadn't been offered yet. In that case, individuals from prior cohorts may serve as excellent matches and confounding would be reduced.

Which of these two is going to occur in your dataset is a substantive, not statistical, matter, so there is no advice we can give without expertise on the nature of the treatment, outcome, participants, and cohort effects. Ideally you as an expert can assess the degree to which each comparison would be valid and can communicate to your audience what assumptions each estimate requires.

There are some ways you can increase the robustness of your results, especially if you can find good matches from both the contemporaneous cohort and the prior cohort. First, you can simply run both analyses and see if they match up or at last support the same conclusion. Second, you can try to find units in the prior cohort that are similar to your untreated units, estimate the pure cohort effect without treatment, find units in the prior cohort that are similar to your treated units, estimate the treatment effect (which may combine the true treatment and cohort effects), and then subtract off the original cohort effect estimate. This is similar to the logic of difference-in-differences when used on cross-sectional panel datasets.

Comment: Thanks Noah! In terms of your second suggestion, does that mean one would estimate the overall cohort effect (differences in outcomes between T-1 and T cohorts) and subtract that from the estimated treatment effect arising from PSM using the T-1 cohort as a control? If so, we would have to assume the overall cohort effect is homogenous (or at least, on average the same as the cohort effect for the matched T-1 participants). And of course, we cannot check that because the cohort effect and true treatment effect are tangled up (as you point out)!